# Strange Characters in R Console and Notebook

Tags: r, rstudio

I'm seeing strange characters in my R console which show up as ? inside diamonds around the package name:

> package �tweedie� was built under R version 3.6.3

When I try to write my file to markdown it outputs in different but still unexpected characters:

> package 㤼㸱tweedie㤼㸲 was built under R version 3.6.3

Comment: What are your locale settings? Is this on a windows machine? (The output of `sessionInfo()` should give the necessary details.)

Comment: Windows and my locale is English_United States.1252 which I presume is some sort of default.

Comment: And what version of RStudio are you using? Are you viewing the output of the markdown file in RStudio, or another viewer?

Comment: RStudio version 1.2.5033 and I'm viewing the markdown file output in RStudio. If I knit to html I don't have the same issue.

Comment: Ah. I think version 1.2 had some encoding issue on Windows. I might try updating RStudio to a more recent version.

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: I always had the same problem with Rstudio, so take my upvote. Some diamonds showing in the middle of the code, specially when I run the code.